# I want to know what's wrong in my code. A set of 2 die are rolled and random values are printed

Tags: python, random

I made a code for generating random values when a set of 2 die are rolled. Error says roll isn't defined. Can't figure out why it says that. I want to know what's wrong with my approach, I've already seen other solutions to the problem.

Novice programmer. My first problem related to generating random values.

```
import random
class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        roll = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

toss = random.randint(roll)
print(toss, toss)
toss = random.randint(roll)
```

Error :

> NameError: name 'roll' is not defined

Comment: Don't name your functions and variables as same, also you need `self.dice_roll = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)` perhaps

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh fair advice, but that won't fix the problem here. `roll` is passed into `randint` but it's never defined in that scope. @Antriksh you define the `Dice` class but never instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `roll` isn't defined in the global namespace, only under `Dice` or `Dice.roll` depending on which one you're talking about.

As well, `random.randint` takes two arguments, which define the range.

I don't know why you're using a class for something so simple, but if you insist, you could do it like this:

```
import random

class Die:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        if sides <= 1:
            raise ValueError('Sides must be more than 1')
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)

d6 = Die(6)

print(d6.roll(), d6.roll())
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a class or a function for this operation if what you want is toss to be a number between 1 and 6.

All you need is the following.

```
import random
toss1 = random.randint(1,6)
toss2 = random.randint(1,6)
print(toss1, toss2)
```

Enjoy learning Python. It's a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        roll = 6
        return roll

obj = Dice()
number = obj.roll()
toss = random.randint(1,number)
toss2 = random.randint(1,number)
print(toss, toss2)
```

1. The class `Dice` is not initialized in your code, you need to assign the class to a var to initiate it.
2. The function roll is not returning any value, so return it.
3. The var roll contains 6 elements and it cannot be fed to `randint` function as it only takes 2 arguments. So I changed the value of `roll` to the largest number and fed it to the `randint`